# How to find if a dataframe contains any string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have imported a dataset I am trying to work with which contains around 5,000 rows and 85 columns. I am trying to feed the data into sklearn function for feature analysis but am running into an error whereby somewhere in the dataframe there is a string but the function only works with float or int. I already had the issue where nan and inf values existed but have managed to deal with them. Now the problem is trying to locate where the string values are in the dataframe.

I have found solutions for searching a dataframe for an exact or partial string match but have had no luck finding a solution to this problem e.g. finding a cell containing any string value.

I have tried df.dtypes but this reports all columns are of type int or float - it also reported the same thing when there was nan and inf values there too.

Dataset is the testing.csv from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XIlVteHaHFqBXqNApYGb3RoHcBkqpRoR

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np
# ANOVA feature selection for numeric input and categorical output
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif

svicpath = Path("SVIC APT 2021/Testing.csv")

ds = pd.read_csv(svicpath)

#Fill and in with 0
ds.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0, inplace=True)
#Fill any nan with 0
ds = ds.fillna(0)

y = ds.iloc[:,-1:]
X = ds.iloc[:, :-1]

#Remove non numeric cols:
X = ds._get_numeric_data()

#Feature Extraction:

#configure to select all features
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k='8')
# learn relationship from training data
fs.fit(X, y)


# what are scores for the features
for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
    print('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))
# plot the scores
pyplot.bar([i for i in range(len(fs.scores_))], fs.scores_)
pyplot.show()
```

Error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 30 fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k='8')
> 31 # learn relationship from training data
> ---> 32 fs.fit(X, y)
> 33
> 34
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection_univariate_selection.py
> in fit(self, X, y)
> 346                             % (self.score_func, type(self.score_func)))
> 347
> --> 348         self._check_params(X, y)
> 349         score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)
> 350         if isinstance(score_func_ret, (list, tuple)):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection_univariate_selection.py
> in _check_params(self, X, y)
> 509
> 510     def _check_params(self, X, y):
> --> 511         if not (self.k == "all" or 0 <= self.k <= X.shape[1]):
> 512             raise ValueError("k should be >=0, <= n_features = %d; got %r. "
> 513                              "Use k='all' to return all features."
>
> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Can you share your dataset please and how you load it? Maybe the part of the code that raises the exception?

Comment: Not sure how to attach either the csv but the code that raises the exception is as follows:

Comment: If you found it on Kaggle or other sites, you can share the link else you can upload the file on dropbox, gdrive, wetransfer, etc and share the link.

Comment: Code and dataset link is included in the main post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Now the problem is trying to locate where the string values are in the dataframe.*" and "*I have tried df.dtypes but this reports all columns are of type int or float.*" are two contradictory statements.

You likely only have numbers, NaNs, or Inf.

You can identify them using [`numpy.isfinite`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
idx, col = np.where(~np.isfinite(df))

list(zip(df.index[idx], df.columns[col]))
# [(0, 'col2'), (1, 'col3')]
```

If you really have non-numbers:

```
idx, col = np.where(~np.isfinite(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')))

list(zip(df.index[idx], df.columns[col]))
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [np.nan, 4, 5], 'col3': [6, np.inf, 7]})
```

Comment: No because prior to me replacing the nan and inf values the error message stated:
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Now it says: 
'<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Did you try to convert all your columns to 'float128'?

Comment: If would be best to provide a minimal reproducible example of your data and the code that triggers the error. Also, depending on the operation, consider that the other iterable might contain the strings ;)

Comment: The solution provided helped to find some empty cells. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to check which column contains a string

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1,2,3], 'column2': [2,3,'a']})
df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).any()

column1    False
column2     True
```

column2 is true because it contains a string.
Then you can remove the "any" and it will return which exact cell is the string as well

Comment: In this case how do you explain all columns are type `float` or `int`?